# How do i concatenate a string in between to strings at run time?

Tags: java, linux, string, concatenation

I have use case where I need to check if a file exists. But the catch is, there are diffrent file that needs to checked for and each file will have its own method.

```
static String  fileToCheck="";
static String  commandToCheckIfFileExists="test -e "+ fileToCheck+ " && echo file exists || echo file not found" //This command checks if file exists in server.

void checkForABCFile(){
    fileToCheck="/path/to/file/ABC.txt";
    NAMServerLogin con = new NAMServerLogin();
    con.connect(sshHost, sshUsername, sshPassword)
    log.debug(commandToCheckIfFileExists)
    String fileCheckOutput=con.execShellCommand(commandToCheckIfFileExists,true);
    Assert.assertTrue(fileCheckOutput.equals("echo file exists"),'ABC file does not exist')
        
}
void checkForXYZFile(){
    fileToCheck="/path/to/file/XYZ.txt";
    ServerLogin con = new ServerLogin();  //Custom class which connects to terminal
    con.connect(sshHost, sshUsername, sshPassword)
    log.debug(commandToCheckIfFileExists)
    String fileCheckOutput=con.execShellCommand(commandToCheckIfFileExists,true);
    Assert.assertTrue(fileCheckOutput.equals("echo file exists"),'ABC file does not exist')
 
}
```

I tried the above code snippet, the debug logs this `test -e  && echo file exists || echo file not found`.

String variable **fileToCheck** is not getting updated in the command.

Is there any solution to achieve run time string concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String variable fileToCheck is not getting updated in the command.

No, it wouldn't be updated. It's evaluated once when the field is initialized, using the value of `fileToCheck` at that time.

Write a method to evaluate it each time you need it:

```
static String getCommandToCheckIfFileExists(String fileToCheck) {
  return "test -e "+ fileToCheck+ " && echo file exists || echo file not found";
}
```

Then call this:

```
String fileCheckOutput=con.execShellCommand(getCommandToCheckIfFileExists(fileToCheck),true);
```

and note you don't need the static field `fileToCheck` any more - having a static field for that isn't a good idea because

1. you might forget to set it, so you accidentally check the previous file
2. two threads might stomp on each other, setting it to different values; and without any synchronization, it's not defined as to which of the values would be used by each thread.